# How to directly pass Podio AuthToken to podio-go client

Tags: go, types, podio

I'm a Ruby on Rails developer and am now venturing into Go for doing some podio.com API calls. Everything went smoothly so far but I bumped into a small and stupid problem for which I find no answer on the mighty stackoverflow (probably because I don't know what to search for).

A bit of context: Our rails app is already handling all the podio oAuth server-flow we have all the necessary client information (auth_token, refresh_token, ...) and do not need to request that information again.

Instead of doing

```
 podio.AuthWithAuthCode(clientId, clientSecret, authCode, redirectUri)
```

I wish to directly create a client object like so

```
// json data coming from rails
json_auth_token := "{\"access_token\":\"...\",\"refresh_token\":\"...\",\"token_type\":\"\",\"expires_in\":28800,\"transfer_token\":\"\"}"

// creating a AuthToken object
authToken := podio.AuthToken{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(json_auth_token), &authToken)

// so far so good, but when doing
client := podio.NewClient(authToken)
```

I get the error

```
cannot use authToken (type podio.AuthToken) as type *podio.AuthToken in argument to podio.NewClient
```

Can somebody help me with this? It is not necessarily Podio related. More go related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the type of the variable `authToken` is `podio.AuthToken`, i.e. not a pointer, but simply a struct. The function `podio.NewClient` expects an argument of type `*podio.AuthToken` (pointer to `podio.AuthToken`), which is why you're getting a compiler error. The simplest way to fix this would be to simply deference `authToken` like so:

```
client := podio.NewClient(&authToken)
```

Alternatively you can change the type of `authToken` to `*podio.AuthToken`:

```
authToken := &podio.AuthToken{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(json_auth_token), authToken)
client := podio.NewClient(authToken)
```

Slightly unrelated (and maybe you omitted this for brevity), but you probably want to check the error returned from `json.Unmarshal`:

```
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(json_auth_token), authToken)
if err != nil {
  // handle error
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! an ampersand almost made me crazy. Thanks for the super quick reply Andreas. Appreciate it!

Comment: And indeed, I'm doing an error catching when parsing the json. But did not post it to keep the example code simpler.